# How to identify HTML elements (in javascript) in a browser agnostic fashion

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to identify all html elements on a page in a browser agnostic fashion.  What I am basically doing is using mouse events to record clicks on the page.  I need to record which element was clicked.  So I add a mouse down listener to the document.body element.  And on mouse down I get the element under the mouse.  Lets say its a div.  I then use the index of that div inside the `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` nodelist and the nodeName ('div') to identify that div.  A sample element id would be div45 which means its a div and its the 45th element in the '*' nodelist.

This is all fine and good until I use IE which gives me different indexes.  So div45 in FireFox may be div47 in IE.

Anyone have any ideas?  I just need the id of all elements on the page to be the same in any browser, perhaps indexing is not good enough but I really don't have any more ideas.

Thanks

Guido

Comment: You may be interessted in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: @bgy: How will xpath help me identify nodes?  The nodelis will still the same nodelist.  And I'm pretty sure IE does not even support xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE incorrectly returns comment nodes as part of `getElementsByTagName('*')`. Filter those out (e.g. by collecting Element nodes only — `node.nodeType === 1`) and you should have a consistent result.

Comment: Great stuff, this passes all my tests in all browsers!  Great to have an intelligent explanation for this also.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript libraries like `jQuery` are designed to be browser-agnostic. Please use them.

Searching through the whole DOM tree does not seem good approach to me.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot use a library in my script (complex reasons).  However I could rip out identitification code of an MIT licensed project like jQuery.  However I don't think jQuery IDs elements does it?  I know it adds silly jQueryxxxx attributes to input tags but thats not really what I need.

Comment: @gatapia, do you want a naming convention for identifying the elements ? or a reference to the actual element ?

Comment: @gatapia: what is that, you intend do _finally_ ? There must be a better/simpler way to do it.